# Empirical CDF Properties

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose $X_i$ are iid $N(0,1)$ random variables and define $\hat F(x) = n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(X_i \leq x)$.

I want to compute the limiting distribution of $$\sqrt{n} \left(\hat F(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) - \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

I know the limiting distribution of $\sqrt{n} \left(\hat F(0) - \frac{1}{2}\right)$ is $N(0,1/2)$ by the central limit theorem and that $\hat F(1/\sqrt{n}) - \hat F(0) \xrightarrow{P} 0$ (since both of the $\hat F$ terms tend to $1/2$ in probability), but I can't decipher this because it would suffice to show $\sqrt{n}(\hat F(1/\sqrt{n}) - \hat F(0)) \xrightarrow{P} 0$.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For large $n$, I would think you may have the following as slightly abusive approximations, though the last is meaningful as convergence in distribution

- $P\left(Xi \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) \approx \frac12 + \frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}$
- $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}\left(X_i \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \sim Bin\left(n, \frac12 + \frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}\right)$
- $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(X_i \leq x) \sim N\left(\frac n2 + \frac n{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}, \frac n4\right)$ where the second parameter is the variance (you seem to prefer the standard deviation)
- $\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(X_i \leq x) \sim N\left(\frac 12 + \frac 1{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}, \frac 1{4n}\right)$
- $\sqrt{n}\left(\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}(X_i \leq x) -\frac12\right)\sim N\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{2 \pi}}, \frac 1{4}\right)$

As an illustration in R with $n=100$, remembering that we are in fact looking at a binomial random variable with adjusted scale and location, so discrete with gaps between the values of $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$, the simulation give mean and variance close to the predicted and a shape close to the corresponding normal distribution:

```
set.seed(2020)
n <- 100
cases <- 10^5
Y <- numeric(cases)
for (i in 1:cases){
  Y[i] <- sqrt(n)*((1/n)*sum(rnorm(n) <= 1/sqrt(n)) -1/2)
  }
c(mean(Y), var(Y))
# 0.3972250 0.2489453
c(1/sqrt(2*pi), 1/4)
# 0.3989423 0.2500000
plot(table(Y)/cases, ylab="proportion")
curve(dnorm(x, 1/sqrt(2*pi), sqrt(1/4)) / 1/sqrt(n), col="red", add=TRUE)
```

giving

[image]

Comment: Is there a way this can be shown rigorously?  I don't understand the first statement, and the second is purely an approximation of $\Phi(1/\sqrt{n})$ but how do we know it's valid asymptotically

Comment: @qx123456  The first uses the fact that the density near $0$ of a standard normal is about $\frac1{2 \pi}$ or more rigorously that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\Phi\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right) - \left(\frac12 + \frac1{2 \pi n}\right) \right)=0$

Comment: I believe your answer, but my problem is that this is a non rigorous approach to the problem. The convergence of the cdf at the point is clear (sorry for this part).  But the convergence in distribution is not, as you approximate the distribution and multiply by $\sqrt{n}$.  It would be equally true to say $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\Phi(1/\sqrt{n}) - (1/2 + 1/n^{2000}) \right) = 0$$ for example

Comment: Do you have any idea of what to do in this proof to make it rigorous? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3630831/gaussian-cdf-derivative I ran my own simulation in R and it looks like the convergence is even a.s.

Comment: If you prefer, then try $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}\left(\Phi\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\frac12\right) =\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\Phi\left(x\right)-\Phi\left(0\right)}{x}= \phi(0)= \frac1{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ which is obviously true by the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: I understand the convergence of these sequences of deterministic quantities.  However, nothing in the rest of your assertions is rigorous.  The link I provided is trying to formalize your convergence in distribution argument by saying that $$\sqrt{n} \left(\hat F(1/\sqrt{n}) - \frac{1}{2}\right) = \sqrt{n} \left(\hat F(0) - \frac{1}{2}\right) + \sqrt{n}(\hat F(1/\sqrt{n}) - \hat F(0))$$ and saying the second term converges in probability to $1/\sqrt{2 \pi}$ so that we may apply Slutsky's theorem + the central limit theorem to the first term